# Vue components not showing on Heroku, blade instead

Tags: laravel, heroku, vuejs3, inertiajs

Im triying to deploy my webapp with vue, inertia js, and laravel into heroku, but after installing the database, migrations and deploying, i get a blade view instead a vue component and this error in the console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Syntaxerror: "undefined" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at xv (app-92582981.js:15:889)
    at app-92582981.js:91:42271
```

My code in package.json looks like this:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr"
    },
```

My Procfile: web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/

For more context, in localhost, i use npm run build & php artisan serve to deploy my app.
In localhost i dont get this error.

In Heroku i have installed clearDB and the packages for node js and php.

My github repo: https://github.com/plestau/tweetyproject

Comment: can you verify that you have all the necessary dependencies installed for your Vue components to work correctly on Heroku? Also, make sure you have the appropriate production settings correctly set up in your Laravel application's configuration files.

Next, try to recompile the assets and then push the changes to Heroku. You can use the following command for the compilation:

Comment: Hi, yes, when i deploy my app in heroku, the compiler installs everything i use in my local project, i think it uses composer install and npm install. I tried adding "postbuild": "npm run production" in my package.json and still the same problem.